# REST API woocommerce - Not showing all customers on GET/customers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

### Problem summary

I am trying to **fetch all customers** with **POSTMAN** using the latest **woocommerce API (v3)**:

```
GET/customers
```

Yet **only a small segment is returned**. The number of customers returned is 28 (**X-WP-Total**) which is much less than the 150+ customers I have in the system.

Do you guys have any ideas on why only a subset of all customers are being returned instead of all? Does this have anything to do with how I configure woocommerce? Or am I just using the API incorrectly?

### What i have tried

My **goal** is to create a small application to **look up a customer by phone/email** and then fetch the orders he had made.

Calling

```
GET/customers
```

Only returns a small subset of all customers and the rest is omitted.

**Any customers** *omitted* from the *GET/customers* will also return an empty array when i for example use

```
GET/customers?email=...
GET/customers?search=...
```

The requests returns an empty array on the omitted customers but
works on customers that was not omitted from:

```
GET/customers
```

Yet, given a known omitted customer ID, it is possible to look up that customer by sending a request to

```
GET/customer/{ID}
```

which does not make sense at all.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am also facing the same issue. API responding only one customer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to set:

```
GET/customers?role=all
```

I figured that GET/customers only return by default customers whose role is 'customer'.

However, since I also make use of memberships/subscriptions, a customer would automatically get a new role assigned ('subscriber') whenever they opt-in for a membership. That customer would therefore not be included in the response since his role is no longer 'customer'.

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon the same problem.

Comment: Not sure how role=all works on a single site, but a multisite only lists my own user when using this. I have the same problem you did, where no customer gets listed using the default GET /customers, even though there are some.

Comment: I was using woocomerce_api gem and the following worked for me:
`$woocommerce.get('customers', orderby: 'id', filter: { role: 'all' })`.
I had to nest `role=all` under `filter`.

Comment: Thank you man! I was so confused!